# Is there is a way to drag and drop text or images in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas

I am trying out some HTML5 canvas examples and I have some doubts with how I can drag and drop text, or an image, or a rectangle.

How could I implement a drag and drop ability with the canvas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to drag and drop from one HTML5 canvas to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599801/how-to-drag-and-drop-from-one-html5-canvas-to-another); the questions are not quite identical, but the desire to drag "items" on a Canvas belies the same lack of understanding about how HTML5 Canvas works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new to canvas, as you mentioned, have you tried using a framework like [kineticJs](http://www.kineticjs.com)?

It will take care of your drag and drop, among other things, and there are plenty tutorials out there to help you out further.

For example, here is a tutorial for [drag and drop](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-tutorial/), using KineticJs.